# get variable from sequence or mapping object like tuple or dictionary object in url

Tags: python, flask, get, urlencode

my code :

```
    do_nomor = request.args.get('do_nomor', '')
    bjdt_no_urut = request.args.get('bjdt_no_urut', '')

    try:
        SQL = """ SELECT 
            bjdt_id,
            do_nomor,
            to_char(do_tgl, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) as do_tgl,
            bjdt_no_urut,
            bjqc_nomor,
            to_char(bjqc_tgl_buat, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) as bjqc_tgl_buat, 
            pelanggan_nama,
            pry_nama,
            to_char(tgl_rencana_test, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) as tgl_rencana_test
            from v_bendauji_detil where 
            bjdt_tgl_test is null and 
            do_nomor = %s
            and bjdt_no_urut not in (%s)
            ORDER BY bjdt_no_urut ASC limit 10; 
            """
        conn_string = "dbname='api_rc_38' user='appusr' host='localhost' password='1' port='8765' "
        conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)

        data = ( do_nomor, bjdt_no_urut,  )
        cur.execute(SQL, data)
        rows = cur.fetchone()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()                    
        json_data = json.dumps(rows)
        return json_data
```

How can I passing variable to url in dictionary with flask on GET method ? 
like this example :

`http://localhost:5000/bendauji?do_nomor=DOCKET/ICN/05-2017/5175&bjdt_no_urut=('5','6','7',)*`

Comment: Please add more details as to what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format of url `http://localhost:5000/bendauji?do_nomor=DOCKET/ICN/05-2017/5175&bjdt_no_urut=5&bjdt_no_urut=6&bjdt_no_urut=7`

And get the value list of `bjdt_no_urut` use `request.args.getlist('bjdt_no_urut', None)`.

Comment: how can I make urlencode like above : http://localhost:5000/bendauji?do_nomor=DOCKET/ICN/05-2017/5175&bjdt_no_urut=5&bjdt_no_urut=6&bjdt_no_urut=7
If i have a list => bjdt_no_urut =('5', '6', '7')

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. Can you explain more details?

Comment: the case is :

url = 'http://localhost:5000/bendauji?do_nomor='
do_nomor='DOCKET/ICN/05-2017/5175'
bjdt_no_urut = ('5', '6', '7')

how can I urlencode with urllib to make the output just like you show me :  http://localhost:5000/bendauji?do_nomor=DOCKET/ICN/05-2017/5175&bjdt_no_urut=5&bjdt_no_urut=6&bjdt_no_urut=7

Comment: You can concat it by yourself.